# Android Studio - Download Gradle 0.12.2?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How I can download `Gradle 0.12.2` in Android Studio (automatically)?

I see this website [gradle](http://gradle.org/downloads) but I can't find it .

I find local path Gradle : `C:\Users\Makarem01\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-0.12.2` get me error `Gradle location is incorrect.` What can I do ? I upload photo of error.

[image]

When i use from `gradle wrapper` say me : The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.1.0. Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the gradle plugin for Android studio? Example `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`

Comment: @ Donn Felker . I find local path Gradle : `C:\Users\Makarem01\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-0.12.2` get me error `Gradle location is incorrect.` What can I do ? I upload photo of error.

Comment: I recommend using the gradle wrapper. Select that option. Can you do that? What happens then?

Comment: I am importing this project but get me a lot of error .[THIS PROJECT](https://github.com/antoniolg/RecyclerViewExtensions)

Comment: When i use from gradle wrapper say me : `The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.1.0.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the build.gradle file.

Find this line: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'`

replace it with this:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`

Save the file, then try to re-import using the gradle wrapper option again.